# How to split the string with | (pipe) as delimiter?

Tags: perl

When I use split with `|` as delimiter, it doesn't give me the expected output. Is there any solution to it?

```
use warnings;
my $exclude_list = "1213:sutrust.com,sutrust1.com,sutrust3.com|1321:line.com";
my @exclude_client = split(/|/, $exclude_list);
print "Printing excluse  @exclude_client \n";
```

Output:

```
Printing excluse  1 2 1 3 : s u n t r u s t . c o m , s u t r u s t 1 . c o m , s u t r u s t 3 . c o m                                              | 1 3 2 1 : l i n e . c o m
```

Expected output:

```
Printing excluse 1213:sutrust.com,sutrust1.com,sutrust3.com 1321:line.com
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't use the `|` character as the delimiter, you used the `|` regular expression as the delimiter. That pattern always matches, so the result is splitting between every character. Escape the `|`.

```
split(/\|/, $exclude_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

The pipe character is a special character for [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html), and it needs to be escaped.

```
my @exclude_client = split(/\|/, $exclude_list);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the pipe using a backslash: `\|` :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict; 

my $exclude_list = "1213:sutrust.com,sutrust1.com,sutrust3.com|1321:line.com";
my @exclude_client = split(/\|/, $exclude_list);

foreach(@exclude_client){
    print "Printing exclude $_ ";
}
```

Outputs:

```
1213:sutrust.com,sutrust1.com,sutrust3.com 1321:line.com
```